# The AES return different results between android and on pc

Tags: java, android, base64, aes

My friends give me a `SecurityAES.java` file. I use good on pc, but when I use it on android, the results is different! What can i do?

I use the code on android:

```
String formVals = SecurityAES.encryptAES(con, token);
```

here is the code:

```
    public class SecurityAES {
    private final static String encoding = "UTF-8"; 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = encryptAES("18382360986%2Cqq200600","uu24sfsd8sdggs");

        System.out.println(str);
        String uriAPI = "http://xxxxxx.com/do/httpapi!apiUserInfo.shtml";

        Map parameters=new HashMap();

        parameters.put("token", "uu24sfsd8sdggs");
        parameters.put("formVals", str);

        System.out.println(post(uriAPI, parameters, true));

    }
    public static String post(String urlStr, Map parameters, boolean flag) {
        try {
            String content = "";
            String result = "";
            URL url = null;
            URLConnection conn = null;
            OutputStreamWriter writer = null;
            StringBuffer params = new StringBuffer();

            for (Iterator iter = parameters.entrySet().iterator(); iter.hasNext();) {
                Entry element = (Entry) iter.next();
                params.append(element.getKey().toString());
                params.append("=");
                params.append(element.getValue().toString());
                params.append("&");
            }

            if (params.length() > 0) {
                params = params.deleteCharAt(params.length() - 1);
            }

            try {
                url = new URL(urlStr);
                conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "");
                conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);// 设置连接主机超时（单位：毫秒）
                conn.setReadTimeout(3000);// 设置从主机读取数据超时（单位：毫秒）

                writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(params.toString());
                writer.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (writer != null) {
                        writer.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            InputStreamReader reder = null;
            BufferedReader breader = null;
            try {
                reder = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "utf-8");
                breader = new BufferedReader(reder);
                while ((content = breader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += content;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (reder != null) {
                        reder.close();
                    }
                    if (breader != null) {
                        breader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            if (result == null || result.equals("")) {
                result = "|";
            }
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }

    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param content
     * @param password
     * @return
     */
    public static String encryptAES(String content, String password) {
        byte[] encryptResult = encrypt(content, password);
        String encryptResultStr = parseByte2HexStr(encryptResult);
        encryptResultStr = ebotongEncrypto(encryptResultStr);
        return encryptResultStr;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param encryptResultStr
     * @param password
     * @return
     */
    public static String decrypt(String encryptResultStr, String password) {
        String decrpt = ebotongDecrypto(encryptResultStr);
        byte[] decryptFrom = parseHexStr2Byte(decrpt);
        byte[] decryptResult = decrypt(decryptFrom, password);
        return new String(decryptResult);
    }

    /**
     */
    public static String ebotongEncrypto(String str) {
        BASE64Encoder base64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String result = str;
        if (str != null && str.length() > 0) {
            try {
                byte[] encodeByte = str.getBytes(encoding);
                result = base64encoder.encode(encodeByte);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result.replaceAll("\r\n", "").replaceAll("\r", "").replaceAll("\n", "");
    }

    /**
     */
    public static String ebotongDecrypto(String str) {
        BASE64Decoder base64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        try {
            byte[] encodeByte = base64decoder.decodeBuffer(str);
            return new String(encodeByte);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return str;
        }
    }
    /**  
     *   
     * @return  
     */  
    private static byte[] encrypt(String content, String password) {   
            try {              
                    KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
                    SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG" );   
                    secureRandom.setSeed(password.getBytes());   
                    kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
                    //kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(password.getBytes()));   
                    SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();   
                    byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();   
                    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");   
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");// 
                    byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("utf-8");   
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
                    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(byteContent);   
                    return result; 
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {   
                    e.printStackTrace();   
            }   
            return null;   
    }  


    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] content, String password) {   
            try {   
                     KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 

                     SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG" );   
                     secureRandom.setSeed(password.getBytes());   
                     kgen.init(128, secureRandom);
                     //kgen.init(128, new SecureRandom(password.getBytes()));   
                     SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();   
                     byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();   
                     SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");               
                     Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);  
                    byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(content);   
                    return result; //
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {   
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {   
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {   
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {   
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {   
            }   
            return null;   
    }  

    public static String parseByte2HexStr(byte buf[]) {   
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();   
            for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {   
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i] & 0xFF);   
                    if (hex.length() == 1) {   
                            hex = '0' + hex;   
                    }   
                    sb.append(hex.toUpperCase());   
            }   
            return sb.toString();   
    }  

    public static byte[] parseHexStr2Byte(String hexStr) {   
            if (hexStr.length() < 1)   
                    return null;   
            byte[] result = new byte[hexStr.length()/2];   
            for (int i = 0;i< hexStr.length()/2; i++) {   
                    int high = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i*2, i*2+1), 16);   
                    int low = Integer.parseInt(hexStr.substring(i*2+1, i*2+2), 16);   
                    result[i] = (byte) (high * 16 + low);   
            }   
            return result;   
    }  
}
```

Comment: The encryptAES return a String ,  and the str is different between on pc and on android.

Comment: This code is absolutely not secure and should not be used.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the horrible code, it is probably this line that kills you:

```
SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG" );
```

A random number generator is not a Key Derivation Function (KDF). If you want to use a key derivation method, use for instance PBKDF2.

The assumption is here that the (undefined) SHA1PRNG algorithm returns the same value if you seed it immediately after instantiation. It only does this for the implementation provided by Oracle, and that feature should only be used to debug applications, as the algorithm is not well defined even within the Oracle provider.

In other words, don't use `SecureRandom` unless you want random values.

Comment: If you still don't understand what I'm writing, please take a look at some good examples on how to use TLS. Even if you get it working, you won't get it cryptographically secure.